# Laravel Where Clause OR

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

So I am writing a where clause for a db query that I want to support multiple possible values but I keep running into errors:

I try:

```
$post = Post::findOrFail($id);
$count= $post->Comments->Where([['status', 'New'], ['status', 'Replied']])->count();
```

But I get this error:

> array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an
> integer  Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError
> vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php:361

So then, I try:

```
$post = Post::findOrFail($id);
$count= $post->Comments->Where('status', 'New')->orWhere('status', 'Replied')->count();
```

But I get this error:

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orWhere does not
> exist.

From what I read these are the two ways to have multiple where clauses where you want one or the other, not and.

For the record, one where clause like:

```
$post = Post::findOrFail($id);
$count= $post->Comments->Where('status', 'New')->count();
```

Works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the Builder, not the Collection, so instead of

```
$post->Comments
```

you should use

```
$post->Comments()
```

and so this should work

```
$count= $post->Comments()->Where([['status', 'New'], ['status', 'Replied']])->count();
```

But this syntax will connect the 2 condition with a `AND`, and this

```
$count= $post->Comments()->Where('status', 'New')->orWhere('status', 'Replied')->count();
```

with a `OR`

Comment: Indeed, the method `orWhere()` doesn't exist on a Collection

Answer (score 0):

Did you try whereIn?

```
$comments = $post->Comments();
$comments->whereIn('status', ['ACTIVE', 'EXPIRED']);
```

Works on the collection..